# Выбрать запись с максимальным значение для конкретной игры

Tags: php, mysqli

Я хочу получить из базы запись с максимальным значение `game` для конкретной `ID_GAME`

Пробовал такой запрос:

```
$gData = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `games_data` WHERE `game` = (SELECT MAX(`game`) FROM `games_data` WHERE `ID_GAME` = '1591670')");
```

но он выбирает не ту запись которая должна быть...

Как это сделать правильно?

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `games_data` WHERE `ID_GAME` = '1591670' ORDER BY `game` DESC LIMIT 1";
$gData = $mysqli->query($sql);
```